# RESTful GET and versioning

Tags: rest, http, httpresponse

I faced a "chicken-and-egg problem" with my GET method.
The point is I use ETag for versioning, schematically like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/item/{itemId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Item> get(
            @PathVariable itemId,
            @Version Integer version) {
    return DAO.get(itemId, version)
}
```

**@Version** encapsulates retrieving ETag, but it is doesn't matter.

```
public Item DAO.get(int id, Integer version) {
    if (version == serverVersion)
         //then response with 304 Not Modified
    else{
        if (entity.findById(id) == null)
            //then return 404 Not Found
        else {
            // return item and 200 OK
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see if item doesn't exists in DB but passed correct version - client recieves **304** instead of **404**.

But if I do database check before - transaction will be performed despite versions is equal.

What the best way to solve this problem?

**EDIT 1:**
Server version is global. 
It is used for syncronization.

Every PUT/POST/DELETE on every entity on server increments it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the entity is removed from the database then the `serverVersion` should be rehashed immediately. If *any* change occurs to the entity the cached version in a client needs to be invalidated, with removal counting as a change.  If this is an issue that you are running into perhaps you need to just add support in your DAO to update the ETag hash on the server when an entity is deleted.

Comment: I edited my question. Also item not mandatory deleted, item with passed id could never be existed before.

Comment: Ok I guess I'm curious how a client would ever get an ETag of an item that doesn't exist.  You should only return an ETag in your response if there is something to cache in your response. I can't think of a reason you would ever sending an empty response with an ETag in the header? Can you provide a use case to better understand the problem?

Comment: You were right. I discussed this issue with my colleague and he asked me same question like your first sentence :) My question is incorrect, closed.